# Dropdown Menu Bug in IE8 with PrimeFaces

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, primefaces

I've a site with primefaces, which have a dropdown menu in the navigation. In Chrome, FF etc. it works well, but in IE (testet with IE8), the dropdown menu expand under the content.

[image: Screenshot from the buggy Dropdown Menu]
Green: Navigation
Blue: Content
Red: The Dropdown menu

How can i fix this bug? It must work in IE8!

What i've already tried:
added in the `navigation.css` the following statement.

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-parent .ui-menu-child{
   z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that solution depends on your html structure. Are the green and blue elements on the same level?

Try increasing `z-index` on the green element.
Also if thats possible try giving the green element `position:relative;`

Comment: Thank you! Why it works when i add position:relative? can't understand that. but thank you!!

Comment: you'll get the bounty in 22 hours ;-)

Comment: Huh, I cant really give you a 100% answer because I only know from my own experience but I believe that the red element inherited z-index from it parents (green). Since blue element is further in element flow than the green one, it had bigger default z-index. The problem was that the red element couldn't recieve bigger z-index relative to the blue element because it wasnt at the same level. When you added position:relative; to its parents element which is at the same level as the blue one, it inherited the same relative z-index even against the blue element.

Comment: Haha ok. :) nice guess :P But it works, the only important thing :)